# Force files moved (not copied) inherit permission of parent folder on same filesystem

Tags: python, bash, permissions, chmod

I'm hoping to `mv` really large (10s of GB up to a TB) video files (and batches of video files) within the same filesystem from a shared directory ("source") to a processing directory ("target") and ultimately to storage. The files come from various sources  on our network, but generally with the user that will be performing the tasks (`www-data`) not automatically having write permission on the files.

The source and destination dirs are on a RAID and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and possibly will run on Mac in the future.

I have (on Ubuntu):

- Set the ACL for the source and target directories such that *new* files get 777 permissions and have owner/group set to `www-data`.
- Set the `mask` to grant `rwx` on any files created
- `chown` `chgrp` source and target to `www-data`

I know that:

- I could use `cp --no-preserve=all`
- I could use `rsync [...] chmod=ugo+rwx [...]`
- I could `sudo chmod` each time I have something I need to transfer

But the point here is to try to avoid copying these huge files. And these scripts are running largely behind a webapp (thus the `www-data` user). `mv` doesn't seem to have a way to change permissions on a file while moving it (I get why you would want that as default behavior), but is there possibly some other approach I should explore?

The webapp is in python (using Flask), is there some Python method I haven't seen maybe (`os.chmod()` gets permission denied)?

Thanks!

Edit:
Here's `getfacl` on the source dir:

```
# file: raid_share/
# owner: root
# group: www-data
# flags: ss-
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:myuser:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

Here's `getfacl` on a directory that is sent by SFTP (a reasonable way users will post files to the server) to the server's source dir:

```
# file: test_05034/
# owner: myuser
# group: www-data
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:myuser:rwx         #effective:r-x
group::rwx          #effective:r-x
group:www-data:rwx      #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:myuser:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

And `getfacl` on a file in that dir:

```
# file: test_05034_r1.mov
# owner: myuser
# group: www-data
user::rw-
user:myuser:rwx         #effective:rw-
group::rwx          #effective:rw-
group:www-data:rwx      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::rw-
```

My brain is going to melt...

Comment: So what is the problem with the ACL approach? That should work even using `mv` if setup correctly.

Comment: @l'L'l Everything I can see on `mv` indicates that it will keep the source file permissions, disregarding any ACL entries. Is that not true? I certainly couldn't get it to adopt the destination `mask` or other ACL settings.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115632), which might shed some useful info.

Comment: I saw that, but I'm not sure it applies, I'll have to look at it more closely. It seems to pertain to files *created* in the directory rather than moved. I updated the question with `getfacl` output from various files/dirs in question. Thanks!

Comment: How about changing the permission on the files first and then mv them?  From your getfacls outputs, it looks like the issue is that they are just coming in with read and execute permission for owner/group/other, and you really want read-write.  Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question and details correctly, it looks like you really want to make sure they have WRITE access when you move them to the destination directly.

Assuming that's correct, rather than just moving the file, how about move and set writable?  Like:

```
$ chmod 664 "$file"
$ mv "$file" new folder/.
```

Comment: ... yeah but the `www-data` user can't just do a `chmod` on files it doesn't already have write access to. I really just care about `www-data` user or group having write access at the point a file is copied (or FTPed) to the server (since later in my scripts they will be doing chmod 664 on everything already). Anything that gets me there without storing my root password for a script is A-OK.

Comment: @camposquinn Are all your files coming by SFTP, or also just plain FTP, http, etc?  ie, what's handling that piece?

Comment: Is www-data the user that's running script -- I.e., trying to do the move?

Comment: File transfers are probably coming via SFTP. I'm thinking of abandoning this in favor of an `rsync` daemon that can set permissions during transfer: `rsync ... --chmod=ugo+rw [etc]`. That said, being able to `mv` files already on the server and have them inherit permissions according to ACL rules would be ideal.

Comment: ... and yes `www-data` is running the scripts.